# How can I improve this so the CSV file can find the ID?

Tags: python, function, csv

Why isn't this program working it tells me the item cant be found even though its inside the CSV file it doesn't want to find the Code at all infarct it doesn't find anything everything is always not found also it doesn't care if I press Y to continue it doesn't care it will still continue if I press L.

```
print(" Description    Product ID    Price")
import csv
f = open('CSVExelStockControlTask2.csv')
stock = csv.reader(f)
stocklist = []

for each in stock:
    print(each)


print("This is the list of what we have in-stock")


instock = []
outofstock = []


Repeat = True
found = False
while Repeat == True:
    item = int(input('Enter a GTIN Code of the item you want to add: '))

    for thing in stock:


        name = thing[0]
        GTIN = thing[1]

        if GTIN == item:
            found = True
            temp = []
            print ('\nItem Found',name , '-' ,GTIN ,'\n')
            temp.append(item)
            temp.append(GTIN)
            instock.append(temp)

    if found == False:
        print ('Item Was Not Found') 
        outofstock.append(item)

    Cont = input('\nAdd another item?')
    if Cont == 'N' or Cont == 'n':
        Repeat=False

print ('\nItem Selected')
for each in instock:
    print (each)

print ('\nItems not found')
for each in outofstock:
    print(each)
```

It should look like this:

```
Description    Product ID    Price
['100mm Bolts', '54378438', '0.5']
['Plain Brackets', '17578455', '2']
['Mounting Screws', '84257420', '3']
['Alarm Clock', '46325754', '6']
['Hedgehog Chushin', '22541529', '400']
['Bambo Couch', '17613422', '350']
['Wooden King Bed Frame', '45632464', '150']
['Mirror', '23454323', '75']
['Door', '36546756', '56']
['Window', '36546541', '30']
This is the list of what we have in-stock
Enter a GTIN Code of the item you want to add: 36546541
Item Was Found

Add another item?N

Item Selected
36546541
Items not found
```

But it instead comes up with this:

```
 Description    Product ID    Price
['100mm Bolts', '54378438', '0.5']
['Plain Brackets', '17578455', '2']
['Mounting Screws', '84257420', '3']
['Alarm Clock', '46325754', '6']
['Hedgehog Chushin', '22541529', '400']
['Bambo Couch', '17613422', '350']
['Wooden King Bed Frame', '45632464', '150']
['Mirror', '23454323', '75']
['Door', '36546756', '56']
['Window', '36546541', '30']
This is the list of what we have in-stock
Enter a GTIN Code of the item you want to add: 36546541
Item Was Not Found

Add another item?N

Item Selected

Items not found
36546541
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please reformulate the title of your question. It is too long.

Comment: Questions need question marks "?" It is otherwise unclear what you are asking. Also **too much bold text**.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the text is legible English.  The lack of punctuation and capitalization makes it very hard to understand what you're asking... or even _how many_ questions you're asking.  (There should be only one question per post.)  See [ask] for details about asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your check is failing is because the CSV module reads everything as strings. You say `item = int(input(...` and then you compare with `if GTIN == item:`. This will always fail as an int will never compare equal to a string. To fix the problem either compare with `if int(GTIN) == item` or don't convert to an int (use `item = input(...` instead).

Another issue is that are iterating through `stock` twice. In the second loop it won't run at all. You need to read it into a list. Use `stock = list(csv.reader(f))`

Comment: It still says not found even after changing it.

Comment: I see another issue: you are iterating through stock twice. In the second loop it won't run at all. You need to read it into a list. Use stock = list(csv.reader(f)).